# Cannot update expired ServiceBus certificate

Tags: workflow-manager, certificate, service-bus

My servicebus has an expired certificate. So I would like to change it.

I have tried the following

```
PS C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.0> Set-SBCertificate -SBFarmDBConnectionString
 'Data Source=MYDBSERVER\MYINSTANCE;Initial Catalog=SbManagementDB;Integrat
ed Security=True' -FarmCertThumbprint 'dac7fc30d5c534a151d3f21cbdee557ea9abfdfa'

Set-SBCertificate : Certificate requested with thumbprint
6450F755020335011BC6D6B5522675DCF15EC94A not found in the certificate store
LocalMachine\My.
```

6450F755020335011BC6D6B5522675DCF15EC94A  is the thumbprint of the expired certificate

I've tried following [this article](http://www.gi-architects.co.uk/2016/10/renew-deleted-expired-certificate-for-windows-service-bus-2/). But after running  certutil -repairstore my “serialnumber” and get-sbfarm I once again get:

```
get-sbfarm : Certificate requested with thumbprint
6450F755020335011BC6D6B5522675DCF15EC94A not found in the certificate store
LocalMachine\My.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-sbfarm
```

So,  how can I change an expired certificate for ServiceBus ?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Workflow Manager e Service Bus.

Comment: Any other solution apart from re-installing Workflow Manager?We are facing similar issue on our production environment

Answer (score 1):

I used the below method to change the certificate without any issues. Harber explain very well in his [blog post](http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm3.aspx). You can try the below powershell:

```
#load up the Service Bus PoSh
Import-Module ServiceBus
#grab the certificate based on it's friendly name
$friendlyName = "wfmSanCert"
$cert = dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My | ? {$_.FriendlyName -eq $friendlyName}
# configure the certificates
Set-SBCertificate -FarmCertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint -EncryptionCertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint
# stop the service bus farm
Stop-SBFarm -Verbose
#update the service bus host(s)
Update-SBHost
Start-SBFarm
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work when the certificate is already expired. If I try what you suggest the same comes up: Set-SBCertificate : Certificate requested with thumbprint
6450F755020335011BC6D6B5522675DCF15EC94A not found in the certificate store
LocalMachine\My.

Comment: You may need to change the time on the machine back to the period when the certificate was valid and update it after.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways to update expired certificate

1. Rollback VM and Server time to moment when certificate was valid and perform Powershell actions to update cert. It worked for me.
2. Reinstall Workflow Manager